# IIS Server 2022 interprets files without extensions as an XML file

Tags: iis, server

I moved a part of my web server on a new virtual 2022 server. This is now working, but I can't get Certifytheweb getting working, because IIS interpretes a simple text file without an extension as an XML file.
If I use the web.config from Certifytheweb than I get an internal server error.
Here the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Example web.config to allow access to extensionless json text files under <website>/.well-known/acme-challenge folder

  * map extensionless files (. wildcard) to json
  * allow all users
  * does not attempt to override static file handler from parent config
-->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="text/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And here error message, if I don't use the web.config file:
[image]

In the old configuration with server 2019 it was working fine!

What has changed in IIS server 2022?

Comment: Try  to use this mimeMap `<mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/html" />`.

Comment: Bruce, thanks for your answer. But this results into the same problem, like the web.config file. So my IIS don't like the configuration for "." at all!

Comment: I found the problem in another web.config file. There was already a mime definition for "text/xml". After I disable it and restart IIS, it was working than expected.

Comment: Do you mean that if you disable that mime definition, no extension file can work well?